# Magento 2 Code Repository Approach

Tags: magento2, best-practice, workflow

I would like to know how members of the community are approaching the storage of the M2 codebase (ex: git) and sql dumps for scalability and quick deployments (also allowing for quick rollbacks).

- I have seen approaches that store the M2 codebase in one repository, and then the custom code in another repo, and the two are connected via git submodule functionality.
- I have seen an approach which uses composer artifacts to bundle up custom modules.
- Then there is another which is to just commit all generated code to the repo.
- Finally, I've seen a suggested method from Alan Kent: https://alankent.me/2016/03/31/m2-project-source-code-management-recommendation/. Although this would require db upgrade/code generation/static content & di deployment for each push to a server (this isn't ideal for hot fixes, quick updates, etc).

I would appreciate any and all feedback from those that work at agencies, extension developers, and in-house developers.

Comment: Here is [one idea](https://alankent.me/2016/03/31/m2-project-source-code-management-recommendation/).

Comment: Is this **the** @SteveJohnson? Once again, I have crossed paths with you. Thanks for your link. I actually meant to use this one before, but put an incorrect one, so I've updated my question to include the link you offered up. I'm still not entirely sold on Alan's approach, as I don't feel it addresses the needs of production use (waiting for composer/ code generation doesn't allow for quick deployments), nor does it make local custom development a painless process for engineers.